# Multiple excepts in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, error-handling, try-except

I am trying to use two `except` in the following code:

```
try:
    Contributions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[5]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/span').text
    Expenditures = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[5]/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/span').text

except NoSuchElementException:
    Contributions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/span').text
    Expenditures = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/span').text

except NoSuchElementException:
    Contributions = None
    Expenditures = None
```

The error message I receive is as follows:

```
#First Error
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)

#Second Error
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)

#Third Error
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/span"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97)
```

For some reason, the code gets stuck on the second except and does not try the third except.

If the element cannot be found after the second exception, I just want to fill `Contributions` and `Expenditures` with missing and let the code pass.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful responses! I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This is a single `try` block. Exceptions thrown in the first `except` block will be raised out of this code segment, not caught in the second `except` block.

If you want to catch exceptions thrown in the first `except` block, nest this in a second `try` block.

```
  try:
    Contributions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[5]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/span').text
    Expenditures = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[5]/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/span').text

  except NoSuchElementException:
    try:
      Contributions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/span').text
      Expenditures = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/span').text

    except NoSuchElementException:
     Contributions = None
     Expenditures = None
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest the try/except blocks.

```
try:
    Contributions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[5]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/span').text
    Expenditures = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[5]/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/span').text

except NoSuchElementException:
    try:
        Contributions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/span').text
        Expenditures = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/span').text

    except NoSuchElementException:
        Contributions = None
        Expenditures = None
```

Answer (score 1):

The better way to use same exception is use inner exception

```
try:
    Contributions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[5]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/span').text
    Expenditures = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[5]/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/span').text

except NoSuchElementException:
    try:
        Contributions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/span').text
        Expenditures = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ctl0"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/span').text

    except NoSuchElementException:
        Contributions = None
        Expenditures = None
```